# JPA/Hibernate - Default data

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

When I have create-drop set as hbm2ddl I want the app to also insert some default data.

Is it possible to somehow write some extension to JPA or Hibernate that can do it?

default data = 10 inserts! with a very simple data!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

During `create` or `create-drop` Hibernate by default executes SQL statements from the file named `import.sql` in the classpath (if exists), so you can place your SQL script there.

Since Hibernate 3.6 you can also specify other files with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` property.

**See also:**

- [`Environment.HBM2DDL_IMPORT_FILES`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Environment.html#HBM2DDL_IMPORT_FILES)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with hibernate out of the box, but you can write a small *app* that does it for you. I have a spring bean that when it's loaded and the DB is empty, it reads a sql file with a bunch of inserts to populate the DB.

So in my case, the same application that I run, is also responsible for populating the DB.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) which does this in JUnit tests. Not sure if this is what you want.